# Shouldn't be "intravisset" instead of "intrasset"?

Tags: verbs, morphology, livius

The following excerpt comes from [Titus Livius *Ad urbe condita*, liber XXV, capititulum XXXI](https://www.lateinlex.de/?call=Puc&permalink=Liv_25_31) (emphasis mine):

> Paucis ante diebus quam Syracusae caperentur, T. Otacilius cum quinqueremibus octoginta Uticam ab Lilybaeo transmisit, et, cum ante lucem portum **intrasset**, onerarias frumento onustas cepit; egressusque in terram depopulatus est aliquantum agri circa Uticam praedamque omnis generis retro ad navis egit.

I've read a translation to Catalan of this excerpt, so its meaning is not a problem for me. What I don't understand is the morphology of the verb form *intrasset*, which, according to the above link, is the third person singular of the subjunctive pluperfect active: shouldn't be *intravisset*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Intrāsset* is what is commonly called a **syncopated form** of *intrāvisset*. In verb forms built on the perfect stem, which includes the pluperfect, *-vi-* or *-ve-* can just be omitted, with no change in meaning; some authors clearly prefer the short forms (Terence and Cicero among them), some prefer the long ones, a lot of them use both more or less equally, often as meter demands it.

(While this is generally called syncopation, the short forms may actually reflect an earlier state of affairs, before *-v-* from whatever source was interpreted as a perfect marker and spread throughout the paradigm. The Latin *v*-perfects are not fully understood.)